# OAuth implementation design in Facebook desktop app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, qt5, qtquick2

I am getting confused on how to implement access_token retrieval from Facebook.
This is how I have thought it out:

1. An OAuthorizer class, which takes care of the OAuth authentication. It initiates launch of a WebView window which will ask user to authenticate my app. On successful authentication, this class will store and provide a short-lived user access_token provided by Facebook. This class’s authorize() method will have to launch QML window, thus involving a bit of UI code.
2. TokenService class contains methods that retrieves different types of access_tokens based on the short-lived user access_token – like long-lived user access_token, page_token, etc.) This would be a pure C++ class without having to deal with any QML component.

Here is a rough sketch of the code. Note that it might not be syntactically correct – I wrote it on the fly.

```
class OAuthorizer :: QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    OAuthorizer();
    QString accessToken() const;
    void authorize(); // This method will launch a QML component containing WebView, which will authenticate and emit an authSuccessful signal.

  public slots:
    void onSuccessfulAuth(const QUrl &url); // This slot will be invoked by authSuccessful signal and will parse the redirected URL for short-lived access_token.

  private:
    QString accessToken;
    // Other fields like redirectUrl, facebookAuthUrl, appId.
}

class TokenService :: QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    TokenService();
    QString fetchLongLivedToken(QString shortLivedUserToken);
    QStringList fetchPageTokens(QString userToken);

  private:
    QString longLivedTokenUrl;
    QString pageTokenUrl;
}
```

The part where I have a bad feeling is the OAuthorizer class. It inevitably includes UI-related code inorder to launch a QML window. Is it a good idea/design?

So I think this design is very much flawed. I would welcome a wholly new, if better design as well as improvements on this one.